# What are the career options for computational scientists other than being in software Industry?

Tags: parallel-computing, career-development

I would like to know the career options for a computational scientist other than getting into software industry. I wish to use the my skills of Numerical Linear Algebra,Parallel Programming, Scientific Visualization,Topological Data Analysis in some Research Lab of any manufacturing company or Scientific company.

Comment: Worth taking a look at SIAM's career advice page: [link](https://www.siam.org/careers/thinking.php)